# Can you boot to boot.wim (winpe) in vmware?

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation, winpe

I have been testing my WinPe builds by committing my winpe files, copying over my build to a flash drive, and then booting to that flash drive on a different computer.  I was wondering if there was a faster way of testing this, perhaps using vmware workstation 9.

I do not want to build an .ISO after every time I edit my winpe.  Is it possible to point my vmware to boot from my boot.wim file? or my flash drive?  I have tried to connect it to the vm (which disconnects it from the host), but to no avail.   The BIOS in vmware does not see the drive, but [outside of the vm] vmware workstation does see the drive exists.  Any Ideas?  Or is there an easier method for quickly testing my winpe builds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download Plop boot manager and point the VM cd drive to the iso. Then boot to cd in the VM and it will give you an option to boot to usb. (make sure you connect the flash drive to the VM (disconnect from host))